# python: appends only '0'

Tags: python

```
  big_set=[]
  for i in results_histogram_total:
    big_set.append(100*(i/sum_total))
```

big_set returns `[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0........,0]`

this wrong because i checked `i` and it is `>0`

what am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If sum_total is an integer (what is sum_total.__class__ equal to ?), 
python seems to use integer division.

Try i / float(sum_total) instead.

Comment: when i want a float divide it's always x / float(y); but as ints and floats aren't objects they don't have a class but they do have a type which can be tested with say type(x)

Comment: @Dan, ints are type `int`, floats are type `float` - types are classes. and ints and floats are objects!

Comment: Or try `from __future__ import division` to get exact results from `/`

Answer (score 5):

In Python 2.x, use `from __future__ import division` to get sane division behavior.

Answer (score 3):

try this [list comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead

```
big_set = [100*i/sum_total for i in results_histogram_total]
```

note that `/` truncates in Python2, so you may wish to use

```
big_set = [100.0*i/sum_total for i in results_histogram_total]
```

Answer (score 2):

Probably has to do with float division.

i is probably less than sum_total which in integer division returns 0.

100 * 0 is 0.

Try casting it to a float.